# Why is the type information lost when calling collect on this higher-kinded type?

Tags: scala, function, collections, higher-kinded-types

I am trying to get familiar with higher-kinded types in Scala and so I tried implementing this simple method that takes a traversable of `Option` and flattens it just like flattening it normally would. However, the compiler is raising an error because the function returns type `Traversable[Any]` instead of `T[S]`. Why is this, and how can I make it work correctly?

```scala
def flatten[S, T[_] <: Traversable[_]](list: T[Option[S]]): T[S] = {
  list.collect({ case Some(s) => s })
}
```

I think that maybe I'm defining the type of `T` incorrectly, but I also tried `T[_]: Traversable` and `T[X] <: Traversable[X]` and those didn't work either.

Of course, this works:

```scala
def flatten[S](list: Traversable[Option[S]]): Traversable[S] = {
  list.collect({ case Some(s) => s })
}
```

But I don't want to lose the input type information on the return type (calling `flatten(List[Option[T]])` should return `List[T]`.

Comment: Is the scala version supposed to be 2.12?

Comment: Writing generic operations that manipulate any kind of collections is kind of difficult, I prefer to use a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) approach.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm on 2.11.2. If it works differently in different versions I'd definitely appreciate an answer describing how.

Comment: I think Andrey Tyukin meant that Traversable isn’t in 2.13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.12/scala/collection/Traversable.html#collect%5BB%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BA,B%5D):Traversable%5BB%5D) doesn't return a `T`, it returns only a `Traversable`. The trait `Traversable` doesn't know the type of whatever class is inheriting it.

Furthermore, your higher-kinded type is wrong, it should be `T[x] <: Traversable[x]` to avoid weirdness with existentials. You could do something like this:

```scala
def flatten[S, T[x] <: Traversable[x]](list: T[Option[S]])(
  implicit ev: collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[Option[S]], S, T[S]]
): T[S] = list.collect { case Some(s) => s }
```

, or you might be better off with Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's suggestion of using typeclasses. I would also suggest using Scala 2.13 if possible.

```scala
trait Flatten[F[_]] {
  def flatten[S](list: F[Option[S]]): F[S]
}
object Flatten {
  def flatten[S, F[_]](list: List[Option[S]])(implicit f: Flatten[F]) = f.flatten(list)
  
  implicit val flattenList = new Flatten[List] {
    def flatten[S](list: List[Option[S]]) = list.collect { case Some(s) => s }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see - I had a feeling it might need a `CanBuildFrom` but I just couldn't figure out the syntax. Thanks!